# c# PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters causes Outofmemory in Singleton

Tags: c#, singleton, out-of-memory

```
public class ExtendTools 
{
    // ... 

    public void GetPrinter() 
    {
        installedPrintersList = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Cast<string>().ToList<string>(); 
    }
    // ... 
} 

Main()
{
    ExtendTools.Instance.GetPrinter();
}
```

`ExtendTools` is a singleton. I call `GetPrinter` in `main`, but `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` throws an "out of memory" exception.

> System.OutOfMemoryException
> HResult=0x8007000E
> Message=Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
> Source=System.Drawing
> StackTrace:
> at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.get_InstalledPrinters()     > at Test.ExtendTools.GetPrinter() in D:\work\csharp\Test\ExtT\ExtendTools.cs:line 56
> at Test.Program.Main() in D:\work\csharp\Test\Program.cs:line 32

How to solve the OutOfMemory issue caused by using
`PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` in a C# singleton pattern?

Comment: Use the [profiling tools in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2022)

Comment: There is no telling if this is the actual problematic code, or if you have a memory leak somewhere else. Use a memory profiler to find out.